# Inserting Attachment in Confluence

Tags: html, confluence

I wanted to insert an attachment in Confluence, so that I can access the image attachment for my html image tag(url). But I don't want them to appear in the page, is there a way where I can attach it in the page but it will not appear in the page?

Comment: do you host the html page on Confluence itself or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

one option is to attach it to another page, where your users usually do not go. call it 'technical page' or something.

the other option is to upload the attachment directly to your confluence server, into confluence app directory/confluence/, then you'll be able to reach it on yourcflserver:port/xxxx.png